# Is it possible to initialize a generic instance variable in constructor?

Tags: dart

I was wondering today if there is any way to ensure a generic instance variable is initialized upon construction in dart. Take the following basic example:

```dart
class MovingObject<T> {
  T _value;

  MovingObject() {
    // ???: how to init _value here?
  }
}
```

In C++, you can do this by specializing the constructor for known types, ex. I could set a float _value to 0 or Vector3 value to [0, 0, 0].  Is this possible in dart?

Answer (score 2):

One way that comes to my mind is

```dart
class MovingObject<T> {
  T _value;

  MovingObject() {
    // ???: how to init _value here?

    switch(T) {
      case int:
        _value = (5 as T);
        break;
      default:
        ClassMirror x = reflectType(T);
        _value = x.newInstance(new Symbol(''), []).reflectee; // '' for default constructor
        break;
    }
  }
}

class SomeType {
}
```

Comment: Ah, mirrors is a crafty solution, nice one. Of course I'll point out the obvious that you pay a runtime lookup cost here, when T is compile time constant.

Comment: You are right of course. There might be a better solution I am not aware of. Mirrors is nice as long as it is not used on the client.